# How do we know chords joining secants are themselves parallel? (Hadamard)

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, circles, power-of-the-point

> Prove: If we draw two arbitrary secants through the common points $A, B$ of two circles, the chords joining the new intersections of these lines with the two circles are parallel.
>
> Source: Hadamard's *Geometry*

Below is my proof, to which request verification, feedback, or suggestions.

---

Let circles $\bigcirc F, \bigcirc G$ intersect at points $A, B$.

Let lines $a,b$  intersect at some point $X$ (which may be inside, on, or outside either or both circles); intersect $\bigcirc F$ at $A,A_f$ and $B, B_f$ respectively; and intersect $\bigcirc G$ at $A,A_g$ and $B, B_g$.

[image]

Then, by Power of the Point, we have $$AX \cdot A_fX = BX \cdot B_fX \\
\frac {A_fX}{B_fX} = \frac {AX}{BX}$$ and likewise $$\frac {A_gX}{B_gX} = \frac {AX}{BX}$$ so $\triangle A_fXB_f \sim \triangle A_gXB_g$ and $A_fB_f \parallel A_gB_g$ as desired.

---

See also [Does the Power of a Point Theorem apply to a point at infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834239/does-the-power-of-a-point-theorem-apply-to-a-point-at-infinity)

Comment: For solution-verification, please state which parts of your solution you'd like feedback on.

Comment: @CalvinLin 1. Usage of Power of the Point 2. The fact that I didn't go through each of the configurations (how many are there?) but rather summarily stated: If the triangles are similar, the lines are parallel.

Comment: @CalvinLin 3. What if $a$ and $b$ are parallel? Then there is no $X$.  How do I justify not addressing this?

Comment: @SRobertJames Please do not use comments to improve your question, directly edit the question instead. Comments are meant to be temporary and may disappear in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to prove the chords parallel. Join $AB$.

**Case I**. Secants do not intersect within a circle.

Since $ABHC$ and $ADJB$ are cyclic quadrilaterals, and$$\angle CAB+\angle BAD=\pi$$then their respective supplements$$\angle CHB+\angle DJB=\pi$$and$$CH\parallel DJ$$
[image: parallel chords join secants]
**Case II**. Secants intersect within a circle (figure below).

Since $ABHC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, and$$\angle CAB+\angle BHC=\angle CAB+\angle BAJ=\pi$$then$$\angle BHC=\angle BAJ=\angle BDJ$$and by alternate interior angles$$CH\parallel DJ$$
[image: secants intersect]

Comment: Interesting.  In Case II, is the justification for $\angle BAJ = \angle BDJ$ that they both subtend the same arc $BJ$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score -1):

[I did not review the proof in detail. Just a comment that we don't have to use the machinery of Power of a Point. OP's usage is essentially only about finding the obvious similar triangles, which we could do so directly.]

For a much simpler approach, we can show that $ \angle XA_f B_f = \angle XBA = \angle XA_gB_g$ by basic circle properties.

Comment: $\angle XBA = \angle XA_gB_g$ since they each subtend arc $ {AB_g}$ in circle $G$.  How do you use circle properties to show $\angle XA_fB_f = \angle XBA$?

Comment: @SRobertJames Note that $AA_{f}B_{f}B$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, so its opposite angles are supplementary. Also, the sum of angles along a straight line is $180^{\circ}$. Thus, we get $\measuredangle XA_{f}B_{f} + \measuredangle ABB_{f} = \measuredangle XBA + \measuredangle ABB_{f} = 180^{\circ} \;\to\; \measuredangle XA_{f}B_{f} = \measuredangle XBA$.