# Does the Power of a Point Theorem apply to a point at infinity?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry, infinity, power-of-the-point

It is common to extend the Euclidean plane with [points at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_at_infinity), one for each direction.  The the theorems of Euclidean geometry generalize amazingly well to this extended plane.

The [Power of a Point Theorem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Power_of_a_Point_Theorem) states:

> Given a circle and an arbitrary point $X$, consider any line which intersects the circle at points $A, B$.  Then the quantity $XA \cdot XB$ is constant for *any* such line.

Does the Power of a Point Theorem apply to a point at infinity? How?

*By point at infinity, I mean one the [projective plane such that for each direction of parallel lines, there exists exactly one point at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space#:%7E:text=A%20projective%20space%20may%20thus,each%20direction%20of%20parallel%20lines.).*

I would think it could not.  However, when examining [How do we know chords joining secants are themselves parallel? (Hadamard)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834173/how-do-we-know-chords-joining-secants-are-themselves-parallel-hadamard) , I noticed that as either of the lines are rotated, and $X$ moves further away, the proof continues to work, until the lines become parallel and $X$ becomes the point at infinity:

[image]

At this point, the claim is still true, but there is no $X$ on the Euclidean Plane to apply PoP to.  Which begs the question: Does PoP somehow apply to a point at infinity?  Can we use it to produce any non-trivial consequences? For example, can we use it to prove:

> If two circles $O,P$ intersect at points $A,B$ and two parallel lines $a,b$ pass through $A$ and $B$ respectively, and further intersect the circles at $A_o,B_o$ and $A_p, B_p$ respectively, then the chord on $O$ from $a$ to $b$ is parallel to the chord on $P$ from $a$ to $b$?

If $a,b$ intersect, this is an [immediate consequence of the Power of the Poit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834173/how-do-we-know-chords-joining-secants-are-themselves-parallel-hadamard).  Is there an analog for a point at infinity that is strong enough to prove the case when $a,b$ are parallel?

Comment: You use in your title "`a` point at infinity" and at the end of your text "`the`point at infinity". This corresponds to two different geometries (projective in one case,  compactified plane in the other). Which one do you consider ?

Comment: Which "power of a point theorem" are you referring to exactly?

Comment: If $X$ is at infinity, one can still look at the pair of points of intersection of a moving line with a circle, but then both of the distances are infinite, so trivially the product is infinite and hence "constant".

Comment: But you outlined a limiting process that proves the result just fine when $X$ is pushed off to infinity.  Why is that not satisfactory?

Comment: @MikhailKatz How does it prove the result when the lines are parallel?   To me, this doesn't fit the requirements for proof by exhaustion common in geometry, because exhaustion requires us to say "it will always be between two bounds which can be brought arbitrarily close together."

Comment: I am not sure I understand your objection precisely so let me try to state the argument a bit more precisely to illustrate the fact that it is completely rigorous.  Consider two parallel lines, say the $x$-axis and the line $y=1$.  We would like to prove the result on the parallelism of the two cords (in the two circles, etc.) as in the case when the two lines meet (where you used the "power of a point" theorem).  So we replace the x-axis by a line $y= \epsilon x$ where $\epsilon$ tends to zero.

Comment: Then the intersection point of the two lines tends to infinity, and the angle between them at the intersection point tends to zero. The result on parallelism holds whenever the intersection point exists. By continuity, it holds also in the limiting case when the two lines (the limiting x-axis and the line y=1) are parallel.

Comment: @MikhailKatz How do we know that the angle between the chords is continuous under variation of the angle of their generating lines? Of course this is true intuitively, but I don't yet understand why you consider this rigorous.

Comment: Since the line is varying continuously, its intersection points with the circle similarly vary continuously, and therefore chords with continuously varying endpoints also vary continuously.